# IOS Simulators -not Installing Apps

Tags: ios

I followed the below process in order to install apps in IOS simulators
1.I have Test.app file with me go to Library->application support->iPhone simulator->6.1->Application->i created new folder and i placed my test.app file in that folder as of i knew after when we open the simulator we can able to see that particular app in the simulator it doesn't happened in my case

2.i followed the cd in terminal window xcrun simctl install booted (my test.app path ) it showing error that 
Failed to install the requested application
An application bundle was not found at the provided path.
Provide a valid path to the desired application bundle.

and i tried with different methods which i had read in internet but nothing is working

so guide me how to install the app in IOS simulators and how to work with them.

Comment: clean your project and reset the setting of your simulator, i hope will work.

Comment: Please post the error message you are getting. Also is the app you are using build fro simulator or build for a device?

Comment: @sandeep tomar  ya sir i was reset the settings of simulator so many times still no use

Comment: @rckoenes i am getting this error while installing app in simulator by using terminal window--->Failed to install the requested application An application bundle was not found at the provided path. Provide a valid path to the desired application bundle.